# Getting subset of application.properties by prefix

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have (partly) this `application.properties` in my Spring Boot app:

```
spring.main.banner-mode = off

app.set.a = 100
app.set.b = abc
app.set.c

# ...
```

I want to get injected a Properties object with all keys/values with prefix "app.". Something directly like this:

```
@Value(value="${app.*}")
private Properties appProperties; // this obviously won´t work
```

Comment: Why do u care if it has all properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried with Properties. But this is how you do with a Map.

application.yml:

```
test:
    my-map:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
```

Java:

```
@Service
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="test")
public class MyService {
    private Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(); // add getter
}
```